# Ruby - at least one item in array ALSO in line

Tags: ruby, regex

Given this array:

```
["/Item A/", "/Item B/"]
```

and a line:

```
Here's a line of text that includes /Item B/
```

what's a good, idiomatic, Ruby way of checking if the line includes at least one phrase from the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of ways.  Speed may depend on the size of your array and line.  Might want to run some benchmarks to see:

```
> a = ["/Item A/", "/Item B/"]
> l = "Here's a line of text that includes /Item B/"
```

Then using `any?`:

```
> a.any?{|e| l.index(e)}
=> true
```

Or using a Regexp:

```
> l =~ Regexp.union(a)
=> 36
```

Answer (score 2):

Above answer is very nice, You can also try the following code snippet using `any?` and `include?`

```
a = ["/Item A/", "/Item B/"]
l = "Here's a line of text that includes /Item B/"

a.any? { |e| l.include?(e) }
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

If elements of the array follow a pattern, as in your example, you may wish to use a regex to improve efficiency. For example:

```
a = ("A".."X").map { |c| "/Item #{c}/" }
  #=> ["/Item A/", "/Item B/", "/Item C/",..., "/Item X/"] 

"I considered /Item Y/ and /Item R/. I want the R!" =~ /\/Item [A-X]\// #=> 26 
"I considered /Item Y/ and /Item Z/. I want the Z!" =~ /\/Item [A-X]\// #=> nil
```